# Tomcat does not recognize my controller (MVC) - Error instantiating servlet class MyController

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, model-view-controller, controller

I have four files that I want to interact together: Three views (index.jsp, error.jsp and success.jsp) and a controller (MyController.java)

```
ProjectName
|__
|  Java Reosurces
|               |__src/main/resources
|                                   |__controller
|                                               |__MyController.java
|_src
     |__main
            |__webapp
                    |__WEB-INF
                    |        |__web.xml 
                    |
                    |__index.jsp
                    |__error.jsp
                    |__success.jsp
```

For my index.jsp, I simply put a textbox, ask for a name and wait for the submit

```
<html>
<body>
 <form action="MyController" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

When the form gets a submission, I expect it to go handle it at MyController, which has

```
public class MyController extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public MyController() {
    super();
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String fname = request.getParameter("fname");

    RequestDispatcher rd = null;

    if (fname.equals("luis")) {
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/success.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("fname", "luis");
    } else {
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
    }
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

}

And from there determine whether to show error.jsp or success.jsp, but right now I'm getting an "HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class MyController". What could I be doing wrong? I'm thinking it may be a matter of paths/organizing directories rather than the code.

My web.xml has

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyController</servlet-name>
        <display-name>MyController</display-name>
        <description></description>
        <servlet-class>MyController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is MyController.class in WEB-INF/classes directory?

Comment: @luisdelgadoserranoDid you solve your issue?

Comment: Yes I finally solved it, it was directory restructure what I needed. Thanks to all!